# Html touch issue iPad

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, touch

I am having an issue with regards to touchmove in iPad. When i touch the html page and drag, the whole page is getting dragged in the iPad safari browser. I cannot paste the code here due to some restictions . I can think of a hot fix for now that is event.preventDefault on touch move. But i want to know what is the actual problem.
Anyone has come across issue like this kindly give some pointers like where is the problem?

Comment: Uhhh... That's what's supposed to happen. Also, of you won't give code how do you expect us to help?

Comment: @Doorknob: As i said i can't post the code here.You can give some pointers if you have come across any problem like this. Ok that's supposed to happen means is this the default behaviour of any page in iPad safari?

Comment: If your trying to prevent default scrolling, they way you discribed is how you do it.  document.ontouchmove = function(event){event.preventDefault();}

Comment: @JesseLee: Yeah but that looks like a hot fix and moreover i have some touch move events in the page. So i am currently checking the elements and then preventint the event. Is there any other alternative to prevent the page from dragging? Because i dont have any kind of overflow in my page.

Answer (score 2):

That's the expected behaviour, dragging is the way to scroll on iPads not only in yours, in every website.

Comment: If it's getting scrolled then its ok. But my issue is the page doesn't have any scroll bars. In that case the page should be fixed right?

Comment: Your content is bigger than the iPad screen? Is there any part of the page in offset? If there is, then it's supposed to happen.

Comment: ok..As far as i have seen I checked my whole page and it didnt have any kind of overflow. I also had this doubt so only i checked the whole page but there aren't anything like that.

Comment: By overflow what do you mean? What I'm saying is that if your page is bigger than the screen (this means that the screen is smaller), then your page need to be scrolled to see the rest, and dragging is the Apple way to do that. Anyways, apple's products often have a little drag margin for the user to know that the dragging is working or something.

Comment: My page is not bigger than the screen. Lets say that i have a simple hello world and when i drag on that page the whole page is shifting in the direction i move. This is'nt supposed to happen right? because the page is not bigger than the screen and there are no scoll bars.

Comment: Ok, that's what the last part of my last comment was about. When you drag your "Hello world!", comes back to the original position? If it doesn't, then try with an actually "Hello world!" page and see what happens. If they both have the same behavior, then isn't about your page.

Comment: Yeah. Ok i'll try that and see.. Thanks for your prompt reply.